Update query using Case statements
There is a table T1 with columns Key and Value. Combination of both key and value is primary key and combination is unique.



Key
Value




xyz
123


xyz
456


xyz
890


abc
123


abc
135


abc
204


lmn
890


hij
890



I wrote an update query to update all those Values 890 with 123. But while updating it breaks the uniqueness. There are many such values which needs to be replaced with some other values.
I tried an update query with case statements, but it is throwing errors:
UPDATE T1
SET Value = CASE 
                WHEN Value = 123 THEN 890
                WHEN Value = 450 THEN 222
                ELSE Value
            END;

Error:

Violation of primary key constraint. Cannot insert duplicate key in object. The duplicate key-value object is (xyz, 123)


Show us your current attempt, and the error message.

As a side note, as well, CASE is an expression in T-SQL; it returns a scalar value. If you tried to use it like a (Switch) statement, that could well be the problem.

this stuff is usually hard to get right in a single query. Copy the data into #t-table, then do your update, and then update to -1 or whatever where you get duplicates and finally update the main table from the #t-table

What about the error don't you understand here? You appear to be trying to create duplicate keys; that is not allowed. Though, in truth, I'm not sure how you end up with the duplicate state unless it was already the case in your table. Feels like there's more that you aren't telling us.

This fiddle might help us collaborate on a solution https://dbfiddle.uk/3u6jAh2p

--Find duplicates and rows to update
WITH a AS (
SELECT T1.[KEY], 
      t1.[Value], 
      CASE t1.[Value] 
         WHEN 890 THEN 123 
         WHEN 450 THEN 222
         ELSE [Value] 
      END as NewValue,
      CASE t1.[Value] 
         WHEN 890 THEN 'Update' 
         WHEN 450 THEN 'Update'
         ELSE 'No Change' 
      END as Action
FROM T1
) 
SELECT t1.[KEY], STRING_AGG(t1.[VALUE],',') as T1Value, a.NewValue, Count(*) as KeyValueCount,
  CASE 
  WHEN count(*) > 1 THEN 'Duplicate'  
  ELSE
    min(a.Action)
  END AS Action
INTO #temp    
FROM 
T1
INNER JOIN a ON a.[Value]=t1.[Value] AND a.[Key]=T1.[Key]
GROUP BY t1.[KEY], a.NewValue;

--Update the table T1
UPDATE T1
SET  T1.[Value]=#Temp.[NewValue]
FROM T1
INNER JOIN #Temp on #Temp.[Key]=T1.[Key] 
      AND #Temp.[T1Value]=T1.[Value]
WHERE
     #Temp.Action='Update'

fiddle
Identify duplicates and updates:



KEY
T1Value
NewValue
KeyValueCount
Action




abc
123
123
1
No Change


hij
890
123
1
Update


lmn
890
123
1
Update


xyz
890,123
123
2
Duplicate


vabc
135
135
1
No Change


abc
204
204
1
No Change


xyz
456
456
1
No Change



Updated table:



Key
Value




xyz
123


xyz
456


xyz
890


abc
123


vabc
135


abc
204


lmn
123


hij
123




Solution provided with steps shown to help OP understand the process. Compact version available upon request.

Could you please provide me the compact version too. Thanks in advance ! @Bart McEndree

Compact https://dbfiddle.uk/-FY9pIsD
